# Is $f$ bounded a.e. if $f$ is finite?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I'm trying to figure out whether the following statement is true:

> If $f$ is a measurable function on $E$ and is finite almost everywhere on $E$ (i.e. $|f(x)|<\infty$) then $f$ is bounded a.e.

I used this statement in a proof but it was marked incorrect. I'm having trouble producing a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = x\sin(x)$ (or even $f(x) = x$).

Comment: I was going to say $f(x)=x$ on $\mathbb R$

Comment: Okay, I think my trouble is with the definition of what it means for $f$ to be finite. This function doesn't appear to be finite because there's no $M$ such that $|f(x)|<M$. What am I missing?

Comment: @yoshi That is the definition of boundedness, not finiteness.

Comment: oy, okay, what's the definition of finiteness?

Comment: @yoshi Exactly what you wrote in your question: that $\vert f(x) \vert < \infty$ for (almost) all $x$.

Comment: suppose $f(x) = x$. i'm having trouble seeing how $|x|<\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Take $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x$

Comment: @yoshi Consider the set $\{ x : \vert f(x) \vert = \infty \}$. Does this have measure zero? If so, then $f$ is a.e. finite. And re your previous comment, $\lim_{x\to\infty} x \notin \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

$1/x$ on $(0,1]$ is finite a.e.

Comment: isn't this also bounded a.e.?

Comment: @yoshi No: for $M>1$ you have $\{ x : f(x)>M \}=(0,1/M)$ which is not null.